# Is there a better Pandas solution that allows data types to be identified accurately, or closer then what I'm using?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, psycopg2, tableau-desktop

my skill level at all this is newbie at best but I'm taking all kinds of coding tutorials to try to learn but the need is moving quicker than my skill level so I'm piecing together what I'm finding and learning on the fly.

- Details about Goal

I'm attempting to create a script that exports specific files and then imports them into a Postgres Database so I connect and utilize the information in tableau.

Expected Results: Every hour the script will run and download the csv files from the specific areas and import that data into Postgres database in the appropriate format.

Actual Results: Every hour the script runs and downloads the .csv files with no issue; however, I'm noticing that there are columns in the pgAdmin that identify as "Real" and when those are showing up with .00 in Tableau when I connect to the Postgres database.  ie: Zip Code 12344.00 etc.

I'm not receiving any error messages because I believe it's this part of my script that is causing the issue

```
for i in os.listdir('csvs'):
    if not os.path.splitext(i)[1].endswith(".csv"):
        continue
    table_name = os.path.splitext(i)[0].replace(' ','')
    print(table_name + " table has been created.")
    cols = None
    with open(os.path.join('csvs', i), encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        columns = next(reader)
        csv_cols = []
        for j in columns:
            if  '"' in j:
                j = j.replace('"','')
            j = f"{j}"
            csv_cols.append(j)
    cursor.execute(f"DROP TABLE {table_name}") # If the table exists it will drop and readd the table with the new data
    cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE {table_name}();")
    # with open(os.path.join('csvs', i), encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvFile:
        # reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        # cols = next(reader)
    csvFile = os.path.join('csvs', i)
    df = pd.read_csv(csvFile)
    column_list = list(df.columns)
    q = f"ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN "
    query = q + "%s;"
    for j in range(len(column_list)):
        column_name = column_list[j]
        cn = column_name
        if  '"' in cn:
            cn = cn.replace('"','')
        cn = f"\"{cn}\""
        print(df[column_list].dtypes[j].name)
        if df[column_list].dtypes[j].name.startswith('object'):
            datatype = 'varchar'
        elif df[column_list].dtypes[j].name.startswith('float'):
            datatype = 'real'
        elif df[column_list].dtypes[j].name.startswith('int'):
            datatype = 'int'
        elif df[column_list].dtypes[j].name.startswith('bool'):
            datatype = 'boolean'
        elif df[column_list].dtypes[j].name.startswith('datetime'):
            datatype = 'date'
        else:
            print(df[column_list].dtypes[j])
        column = f"{cn} {datatype}"
        query = q+column
        cursor.execute(query)
        # cursor.execute(query, (psycopg2.extensions.AsIs(column),))
```

The reason I used the above code from a pandas tutorial was the description sounded like it would be the right solution.  The original issue I was having was everything was showing as string I needed a way to try to get those to convert to the correct data type so I attempted to have pandas read the csv and attempt to identify the correct data type.

I've been leaning heavy on the pandas documentation to try to accomplish my goal.

In the pgAdmin4 GUI, it's showing things like zip code as "real" and adding .00, it does this with a lot of other columns like User ID etc.

Comment: you may need other method to detect type of data in CSV/pandas. Maybe you will have to run own code to convert strings to number and first check if they can be converted to integer.

Comment: it could be simper to use `for column_name in df.columns:` and later use `dtype` (without `s`) - `df[column_name].dtype.name.`